# Endpoints of inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is there an available method that pins down a term between two consecutive integers without expanding it in its decimal form?

We assume that a term given is irrational, and an inequality is already given, but the endpoints are either integers but not consecutive, or any two real numbers satisfying it.

To make a good example, we know that $3 < \pi< 4$. By squaring, we get that $9 < \pi^{2} < 16$. But if we expand it in its decimal form, we get that $\pi^{2} \approx 9.869604401 $. Therefore, $9 < \pi^{2} < 10$.

How do we find consecutive integers satisfying the inequality? Or at least, make the positive difference of the endpoints as small as possible?

Comment: Express the number as $x\frac{p}{q}$ where p/q<1 so number will lie between x,x+1

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want exactly. Notice that, starting from $\pi^2 \approx 9.869~604$, you could multiply it by a thousand to get $1 ~000 \cdot \pi^2 \approx 9869.604$, from which you could say
$$
9869 < 1~000 \cdot \pi^2 < 9870
$$ from which we could get a pretty decent approximation for $\pi$. The point here is to demonstrate that you could continue this process forever.
So what is it exactly that you want to approximate?

Comment: I am sorry if I just edited the question with the term as irrational. I forgot to include it in the first place.

Comment: What I mean is that, is there any way to pin an irrational number between two consecutive integers without expanding it to its decimal form?

Comment: But which irrational number? In general, if you have an irrational number $q$, you could just say
$$
\text{floor}(q) < q < \text{ceiling}(q)
$$
Both sides are integers.

Comment: If I used the floor and ceiling, is it considered to place it as is, or do I need to write it as an integer?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "to place it as is"? Anyway, the problem with your question is that we don't know which number you want to approximate. In your example, you have used $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ which are completely different numbers.

Comment: For example, $\sqrt{71}$. Is it okay to write $\lfloor \sqrt{71} \rfloor$, or do I need to write it as 8?

Comment: If we want to find the bounds , we must of course know the magnitude of the given number. So we have to calculate it , if we are unlucky with very high precision, if it is an almost-integer. Only then can we write down the integers "surrounding" it. Shortcuts will rarely be possible.

Comment: The positive difference of the endpoints can be made arbitary small (so we cannot find the "best possible" bounds) , but this requires more and more accurate calculations.

Comment: I assume you want the bounds explicite, otherwise you can use this notation and then you have nothing to calculate, but then the question would be rather pointless.

Comment: Sorry if I made the comments long. What I mean with the positive difference is that, we assume that the endpoints are integers, which means we need to make the difference as close to 1, since the positive difference of two consecutive integers is 1.